# How lbluetooth link in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, bluetooth

I am using in Windows netbeans C++, I connect with remote connection to Raspberry and execute here the code. I am using bluetooth library, but when I compile I have this type of error:
`undefined reference to str2ba`
I know that this error is because I haven't linked -lbluetooth, but in Netbeans I dont know how I can link a library which there is in Raspbian. Anyone know how  I solve it?